# How to scanf to just one dimension of a multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, scanf

Suppose I have some C code like this, which declares a small multidimensional array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mat[5][2] = {
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0},
        {0, 0}
    }

    do scanf("%i", &mat[][]);
    while (getchar() != '\n');  

    return 0;
}
```

and I want to change `do scanf("%i", &mat[][]);`, and possibly the line below it, to something which will allow me to read user-supplied integers into only the 2nd column of this 5-by-2 multidimensional array.

I am trying to find the simplest possible solution, without concern for software security and hopefully without unnecessarily calling libraries.

Comment: @MohitJain yes it is. It originally specified that, but an editor removed the explicit "in C" part of my question. 

Could someone tell me in a comment why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this.

```
int i=0;

do{
   scanf("%d", &mat[i][1]);
   i++;
}while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understood your definition of *"column"* properly, you need to supply fixed values for the second index, and ask  user for the value while looping over the first index.

Some pseudo-code can look like

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     scanf("%d", &mat[i][1]);
```